# Searching with pentaho on mysql with string varible

Tags: pentaho-spoon

I am working with Pentaho. In the transformation, the input is a csv. Working on the flow, I receive a String (str='hello').
I also have an SQL table with two columns (col1 and col2).
I want the value of col1 where col2 is equal to str. Using a Execute SQL script, I have written the following:

SELECT col1 FROM table WHERE col2=str;

It returns always the same error "Unknown column 'str' in 'where clause'".
Is it possible to search in the table with the specific value of str ('hello')?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Table input** step.

You calculate the value of *str* column in your transformation, use the **Select values** step to just pass that column as entry in the Table Input step (if you have more columns from calculating that one, if not the Select values is not needed), filling up in the Table input step **Insert data from step** option to specify which step is passing the columns you want to use in the query from table input, and you also check the box to **Execute for each row** you receive from the previous step. Then you use this query:

```
SELECT col1 FROM table WHERE col2=?
```

Here is a screenshot from a example where I pass two columns to my Table input step to use in my query:
[image]